# Best way to convert string values to nested JSON

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, string, string-matching

I have a string that looks like this:

```
Standard,NonStandard=[Hybrid,Non-standard,Preferred],AnotherOne=[a, b, c]
```

and am looking into ways to convert it to this dictionary / json structure via Python.

```
[{
  'value': 'Standard',
},
{
  'value': 'NonStandard',
  'sub': [ 'Hybrid', 'Non-standard', 'Preferred' ]
},
{ 
  'value': 'AnotherOne',
  'sub': [ 'a', 'b', 'c']
}]
```

I think I can do this via looping over strings and keeping track of the `=[` and closing `]` but was wondering if there is a more "pythonic" solution.

Comment: Since the string isn't valid Python, you'll have to parse it yourself.

Comment: Can there be nested square brackets in your string?

Comment: You could probably use the `pyparsing` library, but that might be overkill.

Comment: @Barmar No there will never be nested brackets.

Comment: Then you could probably just use a regular expression like `\w+=\[[^]]*\]`

Comment: note that regex might indeed be more pythonic here, but the "looping over string" approach is almost undoubtedly going to be fastest in general.